# MySQLi update DATETIME column

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this is going to be something simple, but it's driving me a little insane at the moment. I need to update my datetime column with my statement, however it's not working. Any ideas?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE clients SET client_last_date = NOW() WHERE client_id = ?"))
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['client_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The error i'm getting is `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()`

*EDIT* - Turns out there was conflicting PDO objects inside a login script im using, that was causing my error. All sorted now!

Comment: Well it just doesn't work. Page goes completely blank, no update in database field

Comment: Have you verified the value of `$_SESSION['client_id']`?

Comment: Pay close attention to how the format of the date-time is. If what you pass do not exactly matches it, it will not work.

Comment: Hold up, my error reporting is off for some reason. 2 secs

Comment: yeah i know $SESSION is fine

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a mysqli function with a PDO object.

Comment: The whole script is the same as i use over the rest of the site, and it's working fine. It's just the date bit

Comment: and NOW() is an actual function of the underlying database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's written otherwise in PDO:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['client_id']);
```

should be

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['client_id']);
```

in mysqli it would be bind_param but the error speaks of PDO. $db must be a PDO ressource...

mysqli http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

pdo http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I'm not using pdo, its MySQLi

Comment: I think i know why, there's conflicting statements. I got it